# MySqlException: Table 'membership.aspnetusertokens' doesn't exist ASP.NET Core 5 Identity

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am setting up Microsoft ASP.NET Core Identity on my website as an exercise to move on to other web applications.

I have gotten to the part where I am trying to implement two factor authentication. I get an error as in the title because I do not have AspNetUserTokens as a table in my database. I cannot seem to find the schema for this detailed anywhere. Does anyone know the schema for this table?

This is the script I currently have for my database:

```
DROP DATABASE Membership;
CREATE DATABASE Membership;
USE Membership;

CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `AspNetUsers` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NormalizedEmail` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` longtext,
  `SecurityStamp` longtext,
  `PhoneNumber` longtext,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `NormalizedUserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext,
  `CustomTag` longtext,
  `LockoutEnd` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserClaims` (
  `Id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ClaimType` longtext,
  `ClaimValue` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id` (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Claims` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserLogins` (
  `LoginProvider` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `ProviderKey` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`,`ProviderKey`,`UserId`),
  KEY `ApplicationUser_Logins` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Logins` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserRoles` (
  `UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `RoleId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`,`RoleId`),
  KEY `IdentityRole_Users` (`RoleId`),
  CONSTRAINT `ApplicationUser_Roles` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `IdentityRole_Users` FOREIGN KEY (`RoleId`) REFERENCES `AspNetRoles` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);

CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserTokens` (
?????
);
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUserTokens] (
    [UserId]        NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [LoginProvider] NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [Name]          NVARCHAR (450) NOT NULL,
    [Value]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AspNetUserTokens] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC, [LoginProvider] ASC, [Name] ASC)
);
```